# PNaCl - compilation error "Only Win32 target supported"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, google-nativeclient

I'm developing Portable Native Client application which uses some of the standard C++ libraries e.g. iostream and fstream. When I include these headers, and try to compile the project with Visual Studio 2012 Pro, many errors are thrown:

[image]

According to Native Client documentation, it is possible to use standard C++ library in PNaCl project.
Has anyone encountered this problem before or knows how to resolve it?

EDIT:

@rubenvb: I don't think I am compiling for x64.. My target configuration is Debug\PNaCl.

@JF Bastien: I am using compiler that comes with SDK. The compiler invocation:

```
  C:\nacl_sdk\pepper_39\toolchain\win_pnacl\bin\pnacl-clang.bat -o PNaCl/newlib/Debug/decompressor_prototype.obj -DNACL -ID:/dev/hello_nacl_cpp/charls -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include" -Iinclude -Iatlmfc/include -IC:/nacl_sdk/pepper_39/toolchain/win_pnacl/usr/local/include -IC:/nacl_sdk/pepper_39/toolchain/win_pnacl/usr/include -IC:/nacl_sdk/pepper_39/toolchain/win_pnacl//lib/clang/3.4/include -IC:/nacl_sdk/pepper_39/include -fexceptions -MMD -g -O0 -c decompressor_prototype.cpp
```

Here is textual version of the errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: decompressor_prototype, Configuration: Debug PNaCl ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(343,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find VCInstallDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(44,2): error : ERROR: Only Win32 target supported!
1>NACLCOMPILE : #error error : Only Win32 target supported!
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vadefs.h(19,2): error : ERROR: Only Win32 target supported!
1>NACLCOMPILE : #error error : Only Win32 target supported!
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(470,18): error : 'short wchar_t' is invalid
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(470,1): warning : typedef requires a name [-Wmissing-declarations]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(506,9): error : unknown type name '__int64'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\yvals.h(509,9): error : unknown type name '__int64'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\yvals.h(510,19): error : expected ';' after top level declarator
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\yvals.h(575,2): warning : calling convention '__thiscall' ignored for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\yvals.h(576,11): warning : calling convention '__thiscall' ignored for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\yvals.h(577,2): warning : calling convention '__thiscall' ignored for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\yvals.h(709,5): warning : calling convention '__thiscall' ignored for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\yvals.h(710,2): warning : calling convention '__thiscall' ignored for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(445,33): error : redefinition of '__int64' as different kind of symbol
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(445,40): error : expected ';' after top level declarator
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(445,88): error : expected ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(445,49): error : C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(471,77): error : expected ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(472,91): error : expected ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(477,33): error : redefinition of '__int64' as different kind of symbol
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(477,40): error : expected ';' after top level declarator
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(477,49): error : C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(478,33): error : redefinition of '__int64' as different kind of symbol
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(478,40): error : expected ';' after top level declarator
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(478,49): error : C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(619,111): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(619,99): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(620,29): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(620,29): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(621,104): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(621,92): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(623,88): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(623,76): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(625,92): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(625,80): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(626,29): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(626,29): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(627,85): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(627,73): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(628,85): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(628,73): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(630,88): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(630,76): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(632,92): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(632,80): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(634,88): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(634,76): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(636,92): warning : __declspec attribute 'restrict' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(636,80): warning : __declspec attribute 'noalias' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(713,77): error : expected ')'
1>NACLCOMPILE : fatal error : too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: drop most of the `-I` includes.

The C++ standard library does work with PNaCl, but not all implementations of it work! You're explicitly telling the compiler to use Visual Studio's standard library implementation (with the `-I` option) but you don't need to do this: by default the PNaCl compiler will link to libc++ (and we have legacy support for libstdc++, but I don't recommend using it).

It's not just a question of includes:

- The C++ library relies on the C library, and PNaCl assumes newlib is used (we also have experimental support for bionic, and soon glibc).
- The C++ library relies on runtime functions being linked into your program. This will happen automatically, but won't work with Visual Studio's includes because they don't have the same runtime.

I see that you're also including ATL MFC, I'm not sure that'll work either.

Comment: Removing VisualStudio-specific includes did resolve the problem. IntelliSense is complaining about missing types, but it's compiling. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're compiling for 64-bit (x64) and that is not supported by PNaCl, or so some `#error` in some header you don't show to us (because you snipped out most of the error you're getting) is telling you.

Why, though, `__int64` would trigger an error, I don't know, cause that's an [MSVC builtin type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/29dh1w7z.aspx). Also, use `<cinttypes>`'s `std::int64_t` (optional) or `std::int_least64_t` (always available in a conforming implementation).

Comment: I have updated my post, added "Error List" screenshot.

Comment: @Signum: try to get at the text format of the errors (in the build log, most probably). I can't make out half of the letters in your screenshot.

Comment: What compiler are you using? You can't use Visual Studio's own compiler, you have to use pnacl-clang++ that comes with the SDK (but you can invoke pnacl-clang++ from the Visual Studio UI). Please provide a textual version of the errors, with the compiler invocation information.